# OO PHP public function send array to var

Tags: php, arrays, function, class

I have a public function which we will call

```
public function myarraysubmit($key,$values){
}
```

Inside this I have a `Switch()` which looks at the key and then should get the $values and use the array in that is sent to $values

But what I am not sure, if I am able to send an array to a var function. When I last tried it did not work - should it?

Comment: What does "send an array to a var function" mean?  What did you try that didn't work?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Also what does it mean to "get the $values and use the array in that is sent to $values?"

Comment: sorry I need the ARRAY sent to the ,$values value

Comment: What have you tried? What do you mean by "should get the $values and use the array in that is sent to $values"?

Comment: for e.g $key = registertwitteracount; the value is the Oauth that twitter sends back to the server.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand the question or what you are trying to do.  Can you show an example or try to explain it better?

Comment: I don't think this question was ever clarified, so I am voting to close for now. I expect it is no longer required.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try....

```
public function myarraysubmit($key,&$values){
...
}
```

or

```
public function myarraysubmit($key){
...
return $values;
}
```